# How to determinal optimal GCC arm options from /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: android, optimization, gcc, compilation

The cpu is the omap 4460, it seems to be cortex-A9, armv7, with neon, vfpu3, and the rest of the options. My main problem is, how do I make GCC "know" that the target platform has neon instructions? Since I know it's optional on cortex-a9. I just want to make sure that the programs are compiled to at least try to use neon, as when I compile my code in GCC and tell it to use an x86 processor that has SSE, I want it to at least try to use it if it can.

I'll update this post with the actual info from `/proc/cpuinfo` but until then I'll leave it as it is, since debian's fuse rules are biting me.

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 1194.24

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 1194.24

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x2
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

Hardware    : Tuna
Revision    : 000a
Serial      : 0149c6f40c009018
```

OK, with that up above. The -march= should be armv7 correct? and the -mfpu, should that be vfpv3 or should it be neon? I'm personally leaning to vfpv3, but I'm unsure at the moment...

Comment: Are you sure you mean `/cat/proc/cpuinfo`? It's normally just `/proc/cpuinfo`. Did you mean `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: i typed it wrong, i menat cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: No need to mention `cat`; you're talking about the contents of the (pseudo-)file.

Comment: At least under Linux, GCC [supports](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) `-mcpu=native -mtune=native -march=native` to auto-detect some options.  Doesn't help too much when cross-compiling (using the NDK or otherwise), but it's useful when you're not :)

Comment: that's what I always use when I'm compiling on my own machine, since my gcc is too old to support my cpu's features directly, I figured to just set it to that and let it be so that when I do get 4.6 I can use it just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Android NDK comes several samples, just look at the one named `hello-neon` and its `Android.mk` .

All you need to know is there, if you are only interested about the compiler options you probably only want to take into account the *C flag*.